# Directive AbstractStoreItemComponent in spartacus-storefront.d.ts has no selector, please add it

Tags: selector, directive, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to integrate the new Spartacus UI in my Testing application (a classical mystore application built according to the recommendations bound to Spartacus).

Having built my "mystore" application, which I have tested, and works quite well based on electronic-store-spa... I have added the 7 tgz files in a row "lib" directory // to "mystore".

Then I have done my yarn add

`yarn add ...`

All seems to go well but it is getting worse when I do the Yarn start (last milestone of the checklist).

I get the following error :

```
"ERROR in Directive AbstractStoreItemComponent in /Users/muller/work/VariantKonfigurator/spartacus4VC/js-storefront/mystore/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/spartacus-storefront.d.ts has no selector, please add it"
```

Looking in Spartacus-storefront.ts at the same level, I can see that there is a type: Directive

How can I overcome this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. 

> I have added the 7 tgz files in a row "lib" directory // to "mystore".

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to use the Spartacus application in another application? If so, can you hep us understand the nature of this app and how you envision to orchestrate the two?

Comment: To be more precise... I have a Prerelease of the front end writen in Spartacus. This is composed of 7 Tgz Dateien. I have got a HowTo notice with it. I have followed the HowTo Notice. At the end of the process for installation, I do the last command : "yarn start", and I get the message that displayed former. "ERROR in Directive AbstractStoreItemComponent in /Users/muller/work/VariantKonfigurator/spartacus4VC/js-storefront/mystore/node_modules/@spartacus/storefront/spartacus-storefront.d.ts has no selector, please add it". If you want I can add the complete list of the HowTo file

Comment: Here under a summary of the HowTo Document that is joint to the release :

Comment: In general follow https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/
Note that the latest ng CLI should be available to fully support ng schematics.
Section ‘Setting up the project using schematics’:
Call schematics like this, depending on your commerce setup:
ng add @spartacus/schematics --baseUrl=https://localhost:9002/ --baseSite=electronics-spa --occPrefix=/occ/v2/
Section ‘Install dependencies’:
Copy the 8 libraries into a lib folder that is parallel to the storefront folder you created (‘mystore’ in the general setup instructions).

Comment: yarn add ../lib/spartacus-assets-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-cdc-0.300.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-cds-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-core-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-my-account-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-product-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-storefront-3.0.0-next.c.tgz ../lib/spartacus-styles-3.0.0-next.c.tgz
before calling yarn install
Enable Variant configuration

Comment: In app.module.ts, import the variant configurator module, the configurator re-use components and the configurator specific translations like this

import { VariantConfiguratorModule } from '@spartacus/product/configurators/variant';
import { CommonConfiguratorModule } from '@spartacus/product/configurators/common';
import { configuratorTranslations } from '@spartacus/product/configurators/common/assets';
and add both modules to the imports of the @NgModule.
Also register the configurator specific resources by addressing them in the i18n configuration:

Comment: i18n: {
  resources:  {
    en: { ...translations.en, ...configuratorTranslations.en},
  },
  chunks: translationChunksConfig,
  fallbackLang: 'en'
},